How to upgrade video drivers on Debian stable?
I'm having some problems with my video driver on Debian stable. For some reason I cannot use testing. Don't know why, it was a while ago since I tried, but the computer basically does not start when using testing.
So if possible, I'd like to upgrade only the video drivers. Since I have a Radeon RX 7700S, I assume that means a kernel upgrade?
But how do I do it?

AMD graphics drivers are open-source and already in the kernel so yes, if you want a (possible) newer version that would've to come with a new kernel version. That said, it very likely isn't the problem.

@ChanganAuto Hmmm, I enabled bookworm-proposed-updates, and things seem to work better. I'll update here tomorrow. It's to early to say anything for certain.

As you discovered, enabling bookworm-proposed-updates can sometimes give you a slightly newer kernel (currently, 6.1.99 instead of 6.1.94).
You can usually get kernels from later branches by enabling backports; adapting the Debian 10 instructions for Debian 12:

enable backports:
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main non-free-firmware | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bookworm-backports.list
sudo apt update


install the backported kernel:
sudo apt install -t bookworm-backports linux-image-amd64

(the new kernel will be installed alongside your current kernel, so you can always boot the latter if things go wrong)

install the firmware, if available:
sudo apt install -t bookworm-backports firmware-linux



As of this writing, this will install version 6.9.7 of the kernel. No updated firmware is available in backports currently.
